# jQuery UI Slider - Show max value greater than, append "+"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

Do you know how to append "+" to the max value of a jQuery UI Slider?

The result in the textbox should look like: "0 - 500+".

I've created a Fiddle to show what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/xcxbF/1/.

```
$("#interview-slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [0, 500],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#interview-slider").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#interview-slider").val($("#interview-slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " +    $("#interview-slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean: 
$("#interview-slider").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1] + " + ");

Comment: Yes, but only if it is the max value, meaning it exceeds 500 otherwise is the exact number less than 501.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add a couple of lines to the bottom of the slide function for your slider...

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xcxbF/8/)**

```
var max = $("#interview-slider-range").slider('option', 'max');
if (ui.values[1] == max) $('#interview-slider').val($('#interview-slider').val() + '+');
```

Also want to add a '+' sign to your '#interview-slider' input on initialization like so:

```
$("#interview-slider").val($("#interview-slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#interview-slider-range").slider("values", 1) + '+');
```